# 'I wish to speak WITH a British accent' or 'I wish to speak IN a British accent' - is there a difference?

Tags: prepositions, difference

> I wish to speak **with** a British accent?

What is the impact of using **in** instead of **with** in the above sentence?

Comment: You wish to speak like Brits do  :)

Comment: On a side note, that superfluous punctuation renders the whole sentence completely unbritish, regardless of preposition.

Comment: @ Pavel Petrman: Is it ok now?

Comment: @ Hanky Panky: Usually I speak with neutral accent. However, when I might come over to England, I try to speak in a Brits accent. Am I correct here? ;)

Answer (score 34):

@Maulik is quite right that for OP's *exact* context, both prepositions are acceptable (though outside of "Indian English", ***with*** an [X] accent is far more common. But having said that, consider...

> 1: *John spoke **with** an American accent.*
>    2: *John spoke **in** an American accent.*

In any *given* context, it will probably be obvious whether either means (**a**) John *[always / normally / inherently] **has*** an American accent, or (**b**) He adopted that accent ***in a specific spoken context*** (both are valid). But if there is no such context, the default interpretation would be ***1 = a, 2 = b***.

---

To put that another way, assuming we accept that everyone has *some* kind of accent, we usually say they speak ***with*** that accent. If someone *affects* [*(puts on a **pretense** of*)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affect) a different accent, we're more likely to say they're speaking ***in*** that accent (implicitly, for the duration of that speech act).

---

EDIT: This is pure speculation, but I suspect the IE tendency to stick with ***in*** for both contexts above directly arises from the fact that a very high proportion of non-native Anglophones in India regularly use English (with varying degrees of fluency). In such an environment, there's a lot of pressure to converge on *simplified, general-purpose* usages which are easier to learn, and far *less* pressure to fall in line with long-established idiomatic preferences that might apply to, say, AmE or BrE.

With that in mind, it makes sense for Indians to standardise on *John speaks **in** an xxxxx accent*, because that way they don't have to learn a *different* preposition for, say, *John writes **in Russian*** (native speakers will all accept #1 and #2 above, but they won't accept *John writes **with** Russian).*

Comment: +1 for those 'either' options. Solely for that, I liked this answer more than my own! :)

Comment: And, for the #2, I'd think John writes with Russian (of course, again, ignoring the article) i.e. There are many people from different countries, FumbleFingers writes with *(an)* Indian beside him, John writes with Russian!

Comment: @Maulik V♦: S'ok - I upvoted *your* answer. Partly because it's *true* (so far as it goes), but mainly because it got me thinking about the reasons / benefits of the IE preference for ***in***. Many of my neighbours are 1st/2nd generation Indians, and mostly they're at pains to replicate "standard" syntax, so I/they are more often on the lookout for "deviations" they can "correct". I/they haven't tended to notice thing like this current case simply, because both versions are valid, so nothing stands out...

Comment: ...I've long been aware that the current "fluidity" of IE promotes the acceptance of useful neologisms in terms of nouns, verbs, adjectives, etc., but I wasn't consciously aware of how it can encourage subtle simplifications in syntax (that don't necessarily scream "non-native speaker!" to mainstream Anglophones). It's a bit like watching a real-life version of Orwell's Newspeak evolving - only this one is "bottom-up" rather than "top-down" driven, and should lead to *better/simpler* communication, rather than mindless conformity to current cultural norms as defined by "leaders".

Comment: wonderful points! Agreed to all extent! :) However, just to include that Indians in the US/UK still have better expose to better English. Unfortunately, here, in India, we lack it.

Comment: @Maulik V♦: That should really be *Indians in the US/UK still have **more** exposure to **traditional** English* :) But language always changes, [innit?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/152639/2637) It's taken me *years* to become comfortable with that usage (*innit* can substitute for *any* tag question, or even *Yeah?*, not just *isn't it?*), but it's another example of how IE can promote "syntactic simplification" that slowly spreads through to "mainstream" English.

Answer (score 5):

Both mean the same.

[Ngram results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+an+American+accent%2Cwith+an+American+accent&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20an%20American%20accent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20an%20American%20accent%3B%2Cc0) show that `'with an American accent'` is more common.

I also checked on dozens of news websites. I find both the uses.

In InE, you'll hear almost everyone using the preposition *'in'* for such usage.

Comment: Another great example of where either of two prepositions will work just fine. It's like asking, "Should I use a wrench, or a ratchet & socket?" Either one will remove the hex nut.

Comment: @J.R. I'm surprised to read that you are fine with either "I wish to speak with British accent" or "I wish to speak in British accent", and I'm not talking about the prepositions.

Comment: @DamkerngT. - Well, I _was_ talking about the prepositions; I never said I was fine with the whole sentence. I'd probably reword it to something like this: _I wish I could speak in a British accent_ (or _with a British accent_; either preposition would work).

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. Sorry that I misread your intention! My excuse would be it looked very much like that because this answer got an upvote around the same time you posted your first comment. Thanks!

Comment: @Damk - It was my upvote. I'm often going on about prepositions – how they aren't confined to just one meaning, and how, in some situations, more than one will work and the meaning won't change. I always appreciate when the learners find new examples for me to marvel at! The main reason for my upvote, though, was I liked the way this answer did two things: (1) it confirmed (correctly) that both prepositions can be used in this context, and (2) it added the interesting tidbit about _in_ being more common in India. (I could have easily done the first, but the second taught me something new.)

Comment: As for that Ngram, though, we might get more accurate results if we [add an indefinite article](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+an+American+accent%2Cwith+an+American+accent%2C+in+American+accent%2C+with+American+accent&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)

Comment: I had no problem with the prepositions, but if we upvote this answer, we're telling our learners, IMHO, that you're free to use either *I wish to speak in/with British/American accent*, especially when the Ngram search this answer uses to support the argument is `in American accent,with American accent`. -- The search you recommend is much better.

Comment: You also need to include ***speak*** if you want [a more accurate usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=speak+in+an+American+accent%2Cspeak+with+an+American+accent&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspeak%20with%20an%20American%20accent%3B%2Cc0), otherwise results will be skewed by irrelevancies such as *She married a man **with an American accent***, where I'm sure even Indian English wouldn't allow ***in***.

Comment: very valid point! @FumbleFingers

Comment: @FumbleFingers however, adding 'speak' does not get me the other use! :(

Comment: @Maulik: You'd know better than me, but my gut feel is if ***I*** were Indian, I wouldn't particularly want to learn specifically *Indian English* forms in most cases. I'm sure there are certain usages peculiar to IE that really *are* "totally acceptable, beyond reproach" within the context of the subcontinent. But probably *most* of the "non-standard" usages you'd be exposed to are actually from people who simply don't speak English very well, and are prone to make specific "errors" because of how things work in their *native* language (usually Hindi, I guess).

Comment: Yes, you are right! And this is the reason, Indians are *more confused* because they *know* English but not sure whether the *source* they learned it from is authentic. Even authentic text books here have errors! @FumbleFingers And in my answers I mention this so as to let people know that even if they *read* such usage, it might be *InE*. Stating this, the readers would take a note and be cautious!

Comment: @Maulik: Haha - but we must be careful not to throw out the baby with the bathwater! I love the *vibrancy* of how IE can easily adopt and promote useful neologisms like ***prepone*** (which 20 years ago I thought was "quirky", but I'm glad I have it available now). To quote [this BBC page](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-28054460) *"**Hinglish**" is the wrong term. People aren't just **mixing words**. They are creatively, actively, energetically reinventing them.*

Comment: @DamkerngT. You mean *I wish to speak in/with....accent is incorrect?* You mean *"I wish to [verb]...'* is incorrect? *I wish to fight like my superhero!* is incorrect?

Comment: I think it was clear why I thought your original answer wasn't correct in standard English. I didn't talk about the prepositions. It was about the articles. You seem to often drop articles when I think I wouldn't, and use articles when I think I wouldn't. So it was quite surprising to me when I saw J.R. upvote your original answer. Having said that, I don't really know if your choices of articles are always considered correct in Indian English. Apparently, the OP and you chose the same choice of article in the example sentence.

Comment: @Damkerng T.: I may have muddied the waters on that one by editing the missing article into the question + title. I don't know if this specific point has been covered on meta, but I think as a general principle it's a good idea to correct manifest errors like that, if they're not *directly* involved in the specific point being queried. Partly I take that position specifically because if responders cut&paste elements from the question, it seems unreasonable to hold them to account for peripheral errors that they may simply not have noticed (but which we don't want "promoted" here on ELL).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree that we should fix peripheral mistakes in questions, especially when a question has already gotten answers. (My opinion is mistakes made by an OP are good clues and they can help us to help our OP more appropriately.) On the other hand, the same mistakes shouldn't be repeated in our answers, especially when the mistakes are used as the basis of an answer (like in the original version of this answer). I pointed out this problem once in a meta post: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2788/a-plea-for-better-answers-from-learners-and-non-native-speakers.

Comment: @Damkerng T.:  Good meta post (which I must have missed at the time). But as soon as I'd read just the *question*, I found myself thinking of  Maulik here, who's posted many excellent answers - albeit it with the occasional "lapse". My position, which I'm sure he'd agree with, is that it's pretty much a win-win situation if someone like him posts an answer which is substantially correct, but contains something slightly "misleading" that gets corrected after an appropriate comment. So while I like that you raised the issue, I can't really endorse the implied "solution" to a supposed "problem".

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's not an accurate usage chart.  N-grams with less than 40 occurrences have been removed from Google's publicly queriable index, so the numbers for *in* are missing entirely, and we can't see how big the difference really is.  Check [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=46643663) or [BNC](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/?c=bnc&q=46643727) to get a more accurate comparison.

Comment: @snailboat: I'm not sure what you're getting at. Firstly, I don't *need* corpora to tell me that ***with*** is more common than ***in*** here, and secondly, [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22speak+in+an+american+accent%22) thinks there are about 190 instances of *speak **in** an american accent* (against a claimed 1,040 results for ***with***). The substantive point is that ***with*** is much more common overall - but it's also important to note that "learning" to use ***in*** is potentially advantageous, because it's *easier* and *more applicable to other contexts*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm just pointing out that you're using a flawed chart.  I don't disagree with your point, but you might as well use reliable data to back it up.

Comment: @snailboat: There's still an inherent "bias" in *selected/vetted* corpora like COCA or BNC - they're pracxtically bound to always overpromote traditional or literary usages, for example. That would tend to be at odds with *learners* in particular, who I'm sure are usually much more interested in how English *is used and will be used*, rather than how it *was* used. In short, for most purposes, unfiltered Google Books / NGrams are good enough for me (warts and all! :)

Comment: It's strange because the complaints you just listed are generally certain to be more true of the Google Books corpus than a balanced corpus like COCA.  Maybe I should write a meta post about corpora . . .

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps consider the combination of language and accent...

e.g. I speak IN English WITH an American accent.

When at school, we were taught to take into account optional information that could be omitted if understood by the speaker or listener/ writer and reader.

So my 2c's worth is correct usage is probably 
- speak IN {language} 
- speak WITH a|an {accent}

Comment: I don't think the `IN` belongs here.  Speak {language}, speak with {accent}.  I've never heard anybody say, "I speak in English".

Answer (score -1):

Change your accent to another way of speaking- for example:'lisp'.  You would not say, I wish to speak in a lisp.
You would say, I wish to speak **with** a lisp.
Similarly with "a stutter"

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps picky, but anyone saying "I wish to" is not speaking a brand of English that's been in regular use in Britain or America for over a century.  "I want to" is correct.  "I'd like to" is equivalent but more polite.  Saying "I wish to" is not correct unless you're filming a historical drama set in 1850 or so.

Comment: Yes, it's "picky". *And* this isn't an answer to the specific point being queried.

Comment: It is utter nonsense to claim that "I wish to" is not correct. This phrase is perfectly correct, reasonable, and comprehensible English.

Comment: @Théophile Comprehensible, yes. *Grammatically* correct, yes.  *Colloquially* correct, categorically not.  With a possible exception of the Queen or extreme upper-class "society" families.  As a British person, this simply isn't capable of discussion - we just don't talk that way.  (Unless you happen to be a toff, OK, but then the rules are different on a lot of things. #taxhaven ;)  It's as wrong as suggesting Yosemite Sam is correct for how Americans talk.

Comment: "I wish to" doesn't strike my American ear as a nobody-talks-that-way phrase, but it does come off as either a bit formal or a bit pretentious. In Google Ngrams for 1980 to 2008, excluding republication of old books or letters, it seems to come up mostly in acknowledgements ("I wish to thank ..."). I also found it in a book that appears to be a vampire romance. For an American English speaker to speak with a British accent seems itself a bit pretentious, so combining this with "I wish to" (at least in that case) would make sense to me.

Comment: It's certainly more formal than "I want to", and I'll grant that I would expect to see it in writing more often than hear it in casual conversation. That said, the OP was writing a question to the forum, not speaking to us. I searched through my personal and work e-mails for this phrase and found quite a variety of instances (not written by me): "I wish to add comments", "I wish to keep studying", "I wish to pursue", "I wish to understand", "I wish to share", "I wish to address", "I wish to amend", etc., etc.