# Does "speak using an American accent" make sense?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Normally, we hear people say "**he speaks with an American accent**".

Does "**he speaks using an American accent**" make sense?

If it does, what is the role of "**using an American accent**" in that sentence? is it an object or an adverb?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's logical to say "using an accent", but in your sentence that's an adverbial participle. I geuss, the object is English which is implied.

Comment: You  could say that to an actor. *Speak using...* It emphasizes the idea that the actor is wielding an accent.

Answer (score 2):

"He speaks using an accent" can be correct in contexts where one might also say "he **[puts on](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20on)** an accent." I think that your phrasing, particularly in the present tense, would be very uncommon, but not incorrect. "Put on" would be more common.

In that sentence, "using an American accent" is an [adverbial dependent clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_clause).

---

More on "put on" vs. "use"...

As Tᴚoɯɐuo mentioned, one context of "use" could be an actor. In my mind, uses of "put on" would be mostly in comedic situations, like someone telling a joke (or doing a comedy routine) in an accent, while "use" would appear in more uncommon, more serious contexts. Maybe a double agent who "uses" a Russian accent as part of his cover?

Answer (score 1):

The more common way is indeed:

- To speak **with** an American accent.

You are less likely to see either:

- To speak in an American accent. *(FumbleFingers has a good explanation here: [**'I wish to speak WITH a British accent' or 'I wish to speak IN a British accent' - is there a difference?**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/86818/i-wish-to-speak-with-a-british-accent-or-i-wish-to-speak-in-a-british-accent))*
- To speak using an American accent. *(I think this implies doing it on purpose)*
- To speak like an American. *(To speak the way they speak it)*
- To speak American English.